# Gallery of images with labels using JSON

Tags: ios, json, gallery

I have not been using XCode for very long and I am trying to create this application for my school assignment. Right now, I have to create a gallery with pictures and names of the item from the database, after which touching the picture will push the view to another view controller which shows the details of the items.
I can already get the array of data from the database but what would be a good way to be able to display the data shown below?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqgJ6.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display data like this [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) is most preferrable choice.

Use [PSTCollectionview](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) : It is supported from 4.3

Comment: Hi Lithu, I have read up on UICollectionView and found out that it only works on iOS 6.0 onwards. Is there any alternative way to display data like this <iOS 6.0?